# Pandas dataframe to json with key

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with columns ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
and would like to export in dictionnary as follow :

```
{ 'value of a'   :  { 'b': 3, 'c': 7},
  'value2 of a'  :  { 'b': 7, 'c': 9}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('ABC'),
                   'b':[4,5,4],
                   'c':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   a  b  c
0  A  4  7
1  B  5  8
2  C  4  9

d = df.set_index('a').to_dict('index')
print (d)
{'A': {'b': 4, 'c': 7}, 'B': {'b': 5, 'c': 8}, 'C': {'b': 4, 'c': 9}}
```

And for json use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
j = df.set_index('a').to_json(orient='index')
print (j)
{"A":{"b":4,"c":7},"B":{"b":5,"c":8},"C":{"b":4,"c":9}}
```